# How to implement scrolling to angular components

Tags: angular, scroll

I have a list of components in a parent component. Can someone please suggest how to implement scroll using up arrow and down arrow keys and hightlight the selected or active component.

I created a sample application below, where a student list component will have multiple student details components.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gducts

Answer (score 0):

There are some options to achieve your goal. I've suggested some small modifications in your code to allow the highlight feature to work. They are:

1. A new `StudentService` class was created;
2. The `studentList` was moved to `StudentService`;
3. a `selectedStudent` variable was created in `StudentService`;
4. At the `StudentDetailComponent`, two methods were created: `isSelectedStudent()`, which tells if that `student` is the `selectedStudent`, and `setSelectStudent()`, which sets the selectedStudent
5. At the html template file `student-detail.component.html`, the selected css property is set if  isSelectedStudent() returns true and the click event sets the selected student:

```html
     <div [class.selected]="isSelectedStudent()" (click)="setSelectStudent(student)">
        <span><strong>{{student.EmpID}}</strong></span><br/>
        <span>{{student.EmpName}}</span> <br/>
        <span>{{student.Manager}}</span><br/>
        <span>{{student.Department}}</span><br/>
        <span>{{student.Town}}</span><br/>
     </div>
```

The scroll function, if I understood well, is already working.

The stackblitz link of this option: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zwqizz

Answer (score -1):

Regular scrolling with up & down arrows is already working. HTML will automatically provide this feature for you. We need not do anything special.

In order to find out what component you are on, you need to implement something called 'bookmarking'.

You can achieve this very easily using HTML bookmark concept; where you will assign an ID to each component and reference it wherever you need it.

Please refer the following link: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_links_bookmark

Comment: Reading the original question, this answer seems to misunderstand what is being asked for. The question is how to scroll through a list of elements using the arrow keys highlighting the currently selected element in the list, not how to use HTML bookmarks.